# Split cable broadband connection to lan cord and router

Tags: networking, home-networking, rj-45

I am trying to split my cable broadband connection between laptop and router to avoid disconnection during power cuts. Cable broadband is connected even if there is no power. So I am trying to use RJ45 splitter to split the connection from cable into two part. One cable from RJ45 splitter is connected to router and other to laptop. However with this setup the internet is not working at all.

I have limited knowledge of networks so please excuse me if this question is easy.

[image: Setup]

Comment: You sure it still works?  Because you normally need a modem even with cable which requires power.  Your plan is deeply flawed.

Comment: The cable which I am connecting to router has comes from a modem which has power backup. So if I connect the cable directly to my laptop also it works (without the need of router)

Comment: So you have two options. An unpowered switch/hub which honestly likely won't work or a battery backup and a router. Spliter won't work in this case.

Comment: I agree with Ramhound. Since your modem is "power backed-up" you don't need to split the CAT cable before the router but you need to set your router on a UPS and have a Laptop CAT cable plugged into it. There is still a chance it won't work.

Answer (score 3):

A simple "RJ45 splitter" doesn't work like you think it does.  Hubs, switches and routers are what you use for "splitting" your network connection -- you need one of those to pull off what you're requesting (based on the info given anyway).

To tackle your source problem:  If you want your router to survive a power outage, buy a battery backup (UPS) for it.

Comment: Or plug the router into the same "power backup" that you commented that your modem is using . . .

Comment: @ernie I'd suspect the OP is referring to the modem itself having an internal battery for backup. I've seen quite a few of those, and they're annoying when you're telling a customer over the phone to unplug and re-plug the modem to power-cycle it, but they can't. :)